# CSS Animation in Firefox... clip-path: inset()

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, css-animations, polyfills

I have an animation that is working beautifully in Chrome but is not registering at all in Firefox. It is an animation that mimics how an old tv might turn on. Starting from the middle of the 'box' spreading into a horizontal line, and then finally spreading upwards and downwards simultaneously to fill the 'box'.
The following is my CSS.

```
@keyframes tvOn{
0%{
clip-path: inset(49.9% 49%);
}
45%{
clip-path: inset(49.9% 0%);
}
100%{
clip-path: inset(0% 0%);
}
}


#box{
...
animation: 1s ease tvOn;
...
}
```

Is inset what is not supported? I even tried 'rectangle' and 'polygon' but neither seem to work. If you know of a Firefox polyfill that can solve this problem or an alternative I appreciate it. This clip-path inset is working beautifully, I can't achieve the same result this easily with any other css property I've tried. Even animating the width and height is tricky because those grow from the top left corner, instead of the direct center/middle of a 'box'.
Also I don't want to animate the box growing a bigger size, its more about revealing a completely hidden box in a unique way slowly across both axes to make it seem like a tv turning on.

Comment: What version of firefox are you using? Firefox only has partial support for some of your things: [inset](http://caniuse.com/#search=clippath)
 & [animation](http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframe)

Comment: Hi Chris,53.0 (32-bit)